# Run a background asynchronous process from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, asynchronous

I have a DLL that I would like to run as a background process. So in the C# Application I would first like to run this process in the chosen DLL then let my Application continue with the DLL processes running in the background.

I've seen a few articles and sites but not sure which is the best path to take.

Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL is not process and can't be run itself. However you can design a windows service and wrap service code around your DLL call to make the functionality available as a continously running background process.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: yeah thats what I mean, sorry getting bit late in the day :Sd

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are choosing the .dll in advance (static binding):

Add the .dll as a reference into your project. Then call `MyDll.Core.Start();` where MyDll is the default namespace of your .dll, and Core is a .cs class, and Start() is a function you defined that does `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), null);` and DoWork does your actual background work.

Assuming you want the end-user to choose the .dll from within the application (late binding):

See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/samhaidar/LateBindingWithReflection09122005053810AM/LateBindingWithReflection.aspx and change `GetUserName` in the example to `Start` to match my example above.